# How to calculate the no of options in a select tag that are not disabled and has display none property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select tag that has options and at some point some of the options are disabled and hidden. I want to get the size or length of the options.

I tried

```
$("#input option :enabled").size();
```

And :

```
x=$("#input option").length
y=$("#input option :disabled").length;
count = x-y;
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: Use `$("#input option:not(:disabled)").length;`, (i hope that element with id `#input` is a select tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$("#input option:not(:hidden):not(:disabled)").length
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with simple selectors.

```js
length = $("#input option:not(:disabled)").filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('display') != 'none';
}).length;
console.log(length);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = length;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input">
  <option disabled="true">1</option>
  <option disabled="true">2</option>
  <option disabled="true">3</option>
  <option style="display:none;">4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>0</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function, and using two conditions, first check for options that are not disabled, and second it this ones has `display=none`, check example below.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var options_length = $("#input option").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).css("display") == "none" && $(this).not(':disabled')
}).length;

alert(options_length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" id='input'>
  <option value="value1">Valeur 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Valeur 2</option>
  <option value="value3" style='display:none'>Valeur 3</option>
  <option value="value4" disabled>Valeur 4</option>
  <option value="value5" disabled>Valeur 5</option>
  <option value="value6">Valeur 6</option>
  <option value="value7" style='display:none'>Valeur 7</option>
</select>
```